# Как работает такая конструкция public function Name (Closure $closure){}

Tags: php, ооп, laravel

Вызывают в начале кода use Closure; это есть внутренний класс php Closure а далее используют внутри функции переменную $closure; из мануала совершенно не понятно как работать и применять такую переменную.

**UPD**

Вот так это использует во фреймворке laravel, только я не понимаю что этим пытаются добиться?

```
public function extend($abstract, Closure $closure)

{
    $abstract = $this->normalize($abstract);

    if (isset($this->instances[$abstract])) {
        $this->instances[$abstract] = $closure($this->instances[$abstract], $this);
        $this->rebound($abstract);

    } else {

        $this->extenders[$abstract][] = $closure; 

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Объект класса Closure не предназначен для инстанциирования с помощью оператора `new`, так как имеет приватный конструктор. Это "служебный" класс PHP, который используется для создания [анонимных функций](http://php.net/manual/ru/functions.anonymous.php).

Конструкция

```
public function Name (Closure $closure){}
```

говорит нам, что данная функция принимает в качестве параметра анонимную функцию. Вызов ее в коде будет выглядеть так:

```
$variable = Name(function(параметры){что-то делаем;});
```

Answer (score 1):

[`Closure`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.closure.php) - это детали реализации замыкания, т.е. анонимных функций.

```
public function Name (Closure $closure){}
```

Запись утверждает, что методу должен быть передан один аргумент и этот аргумент должен являться замыканием. Т.е. в простом случае вот так:

```
$object->Name(function() {
    // какие-то действия
});
```

Функцию в метод обычно передают с одной целью - чтобы этот метод был где-то вызван. А вызвать функцию можно разными методами, например:

```
$closure(); // вот так
call_user_func($closure); // или так
```

Или передать в какую-то другую функцию, которая принимает параметром `callback`. Можно передавать дополнительные аргументы в функцию.

Замечу, что требовать именно `Closure` довольно странно и оправдано только в том случае, если вы собираетесь использовать методы именно класса `Closure`. В общем случае для указания необходимости передать в метод функцию необходимо указывать [`callable`](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration), что позволяет использовать любой из вариантов передачи этого [псевдотипа](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php).

Answer (score 0):

Вот так это использует во фреймворке laravel, только я не понимаю что этим пытаются добиться.

```
public function extend($abstract, Closure $closure)

{
    $abstract = $this->normalize($abstract);

    if (isset($this->instances[$abstract])) {
        $this->instances[$abstract] = $closure($this->instances[$abstract], $this);
        $this->rebound($abstract);

    } else {

        $this->extenders[$abstract][] = $closure; 

    }
}
```